# Can produce angular JS output

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a simple hello world example straight out of book but somehow i cant get it correct. not sure what is going on here.

html Code, angular.js is the latest 1.3.x downloaded from angularjs site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller.js

```
function HelloController($scope){
  $scope.greeting={text:'Hello'};
}
```

why can i get Hello world in the output when i load the html page. Instead i see this

{{greeting.text}}, World

what is going on?

Comment: missing div closing tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what will work for you:

```js
function HelloController($scope) {
    $scope.greeting={text:'Hello'};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="HelloController">
    <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, why is that?. why cant i use local angular javascript file?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='HelloController'>
      <p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is why I use IDEs that auto-add ending tags. ;)